# Convergence of a sequence of norm

Tags: real-analysis

Let be (X,$||.||$) a normed space and $\{x_n\}$ a Cauchy sequence. Then $\{||x_n||\}$ is convergent.

My attemp: if $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy then $\forall \epsilon >0$ exists $N>0: \forall n,m\ge N \quad||x_n-x_m||<\epsilon$.

Then $\big| ||x_n||-||x_m||\big |\le ||x_n-x_m||<\epsilon \quad \forall n,m\ge N$ so $\{||x_n||\}$ is Cauchy sequence.

But how can I prove is convergent?

Comment: $\{\lVert x_n\rVert\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re almost there! $\left\|x\right\|$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. And since the reals are a complete metric space them every Cauchy sequence converges.

Comment: the sequence is also bounded?

Comment: Well, every Cauchy sequence is bounded.